# Release ClassLoader reference failed

Tags: java, garbage-collection, java-native-interface, classloader

i will implement a typical native library loading. The target process:

1. Extract the native library from jar
2. Put it in a unique temp directory
3. Load the native library to JVM

The central issue is the removing of the temporary extracted native library files. The DELETE_ON_EXIT method dosen't work. The reason for that is, the files can not delete if the librarys are not unload from JVM. But will not be unloaded before the ClassLoader is  garbage collected.

An tip I'm readed, is the using of a custom ClassLoader (http://www.codethesis.com/blog/unload-java-jni-dll). I implement a simple test with custom ClassLoader, but it will not garbage collect the custom ClassLaoder. Here are the sample code:

**Custom ClassLoader**

```
package minloader;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class NativeLibraryLoaderClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{
      @Override
    public Class<?> findClass(final String name) throws ClassNotFoundException 
    {
        try 
        {
            final byte[] classData = loadClassData(name);
            final Class<?> clazz = defineClass(name, classData, 0, classData.length);
            resolveClass(clazz);

            return clazz;
        } 
        catch (final IOException ex) 
        {
            throw new ClassNotFoundException("Class [" + name+ "] could not be found", ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Loads the class file into <code>byte[]</code>.
     * @param name The name of the class e.g. de.sitec.nativelibraryloadert.LoadEngine}
     * @return The class file as <code>byte[]</code>
     * @throws IOException If the reading of the class file has failed
     * @since 1.0
     */
    private static byte[] loadClassData(String name) throws IOException 
    {
        try(final BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(name.replace(".", "/")
                        + ".class"));
                final ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream())
        {
            int i;

            while ((i = in.read()) != -1) 
            {
                bos.write(i);
            }

            return bos.toByteArray();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        return NativeLibraryLoaderClassLoader.class.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public void finalize() {
        System.out.println("A garbage collected - LOADER");
    }
}
```

**Native Interface**

```
package minloader;

/**
 *
 * @author RD3
 */
public interface Native
{
    public boolean initializeAPI();
}
```

**Native Impl**

```
package minloader;

public class NativeImpl implements Native
{

    /**
     * Initializes the NativeImpl API
     *
     * @return a boolean to indicate if API is successfully loaded
     */
    @Override
    public boolean initializeAPI(){return true;}

    @Override
    public void finalize() {
        System.out.println("A garbage collected - Native");
    }
```

**Main**

```
package minloader;

/**
 *
 * @author RD3
 */
public class MinLoader
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        NativeLibraryLoaderClassLoader nl = null;
        Class pc = null;
        Native pcan = null;
        try
        {
            nl = new NativeLibraryLoaderClassLoader();
            pc = nl.findClass("minloader.NativeImpl");
            pcan = (Native)pc.newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            System.out.println("CLEAN UP");

            if(pcan != null)
            {
                pcan = null;
            }

            if(pc != null)
            {
                pc = null;
            }
            if(nl != null)
            {
                nl = null;
            }
            System.gc();
            System.gc();
            System.gc();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("CLEANED");
        }

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

}
```

If i remove the line `pcan = (Native)pc.newInstance();` then the custom ClassLoder will garbage collect.

What is wrong?

regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are trying to do.  You can try intermixing runFinalization() calls between System.gc(), but ultimately there is still no guarantee that the ClassLoader will be garbage collected.

(Note that using findClass directly is awkward.  Presumably you're using that because the class is otherwise not actually loaded by NativeLibraryLoaderClassLoader.  That's because you're using the no-arg ClassLoader constructor, which uses the application class loader as the parent by default.  If you add `NativeLibraryLoaderClassLoader() { super(null); }`, then you should be able to switch to loadClass.)

Comment: I have added constructor with super(null) and test with loadClass but the issue is the same before. The ClassLoder will never garbage collected after the creation of the instance of NativeImpl.

Comment: There is no way to do what you're trying to do. The super(null) thing is completely unrelated, I was just highlighting something else in your code in case you were curious.